# Order by date date with linq and entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, entity, sql-order-by

I have this code:

```
List<jogo> lista_realizados = tt.jogo.Where(c => c.activo == 1 && 
                                                 c.progresso == 2 && 
                                                 c.id_torneio == torn.id_torneio)
                                     .ToList();
var q1 = lista_realizados.Select(c => new { resultado = c.resultado, 
                                            id = c.id_jogo,
                                            torneio = c.torneios.nome, 
                                            Data = c.data, 
                                            Hora = c.hora, 
                                            jogador = c.jogador.Nome_jogador, 
                                            jogador2 = c.jogador2.Nome_jogador, 
                                            Clube = c.clubeparceiro.nome, 
                                            agendadopor = c.alterado_por}) 
                          .OrderByDescending(p =>  p.Data.Value.Month )
                          .ToList();

gvListaJogos.DataSource = q1;


gvListaJogos.DataBind();
```

I get the list and then I try to order the list by the field `Data` - it is defined as a `Date` in sql. And in the code appeared as a `?Datetime`.

But it seems that the list is being ordered by string and not by the date.

Comment: Please show the definition of jogo

Comment: You say `Data` is `?DateTime`, but then you have `Data.Value` -- `DateTime` does not have a `Value` property.  So show us the definition of jogo.

Comment: What is the type of `Data` and `Data.Value` resp. `Data.Value.Month`?

Comment: jogo is defined in the database as a Date.. im using entity framework to get the object..
the Data appears as a DateTime?

Comment: When you have to deal with nullable, what I always do is I use a ternary operator. So in your case, I would do this: `OrderByDescending(p => (p.Data != null) ? p.Data.Value.Month : 12)` 

12 being the biggest value possible for a month so any null value will be listed at the end.

Comment: @user2146290 jogo is not a date.  The code is `List<jogo> ...`. jogo is clearly a class that has a number of members.  Please show its definition

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that gvListaJogos is a ListBox.

Make sure the Sorted property of the ListBox is set to false.

Comment: gvListaJogos its a gridview!